# OS X Yosemite focuses automatically

Tags: macos, mac

Lately I started experiencing that - 'issue' / 'bug' / 'feature' on my MacBook Air with OS X Yosemite.

Whenever I open a new window (of any app) something gets focused immediately (getting that selection frame around it, usually blue).
That happens in notification center as well. That's really annoying.

Anyone knows how to get rid of it?

Here's an example, look at the segment control:

[image: OS X Yosemite Focus]

Answer (score 2):

This is because **Full Keyboard Access** is turned on. To turn it off, go to 
*System Preferences*, *Keyboard*, *Shortcuts* tab, and select *Text boxes and lists only* at the bottom.

Alternatively, Control-F7 will toggle this.